# Vuejs get data from array and place them in another array

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have this code

```
let route = res.data.data;
console.log('data to be loop: ', route)

var ddd = [];
for(let i = 0; i < route.length; i++){
  ddd = [...route[i].longitude, ...route[i].latitude]
}
console.log('final data: ', ddd)
```

The result of code above is:

[image: one]

What I'm trying to do is to get `longitude, latitude` of each row and place them as separate array into `ddd` array. something like this:

```
ddd = [
  0: {
     lat: xxxxx,
     lng: xxxxx
  },
  1: {
     lat: xxxxx,
     lng: xxxxx
  }
]
```

**What should I change in my code to achieve that?**

Comment: since those properties are not arrays, you wouldn't use `...route[i].longitude` - more like `ddd.push({lat:route[i].latitude, lng:route[i].longitude}` - or better yet `var ddd = route.map(({longitude:lng, latitude:lat}) => ({lng, lat}));`

Comment: can you paste your json instead of snapshot

Comment: `...route[i].longitude` is spreading each character of the `latitude` and `longitude` string to the array and it is being replaced in each loop

Comment: @adiga what should i do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [JavaScript map function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). Your code would become:

```js
let route = res.data.data;

const ddd = route.map((element) => {
  return {
    lat: element.latitude,
    lng: element.latitude,
  };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
let route = res.data.data;
console.log('data to be loop: ', route)

let ddd = route.map(x => {
    return {
        lng: x.longitude,
        lat: x.latitude
    }
})

console.log('final data: ', ddd)
```